# How can I synchronize podcasts using Ubuntu One?

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-one, sync, rhythmbox, podcast

I use Rhythmbox's podcast feature, to automatically download new podcast episodes from feeds which I've subscribed to. I also happen to use Ubuntu on several computers, all synced to the same Ubuntu One account.

What I want to do, is to synchronize **downloaded podcasts** as well as Rhythmbox's **list of podcast subscriptions** between my computers, so that the podcast view in Rhythmbox appear the same on all computers. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locate the files you wish to  sync
Then, via ln -s you can link them into your Ubuntu One Folder.
For example: I want to link 123.txt in my home folder to my Ubuntu One:

```
ln -s /home/name/123.txt /home/name/"Ubuntu One"
```

It is "Ubuntu One" and not just without " because there is an space in the folder name.

In your case it is the opposite way, as you want the files to be stored in your Ubuntu One:

```
ln -s /home/name/"Ubuntu One"/Podcasts /home/name/Podcasts
```

Do this on every computer you want to sync with

Comment: Your Podcast subcription is probably somewhere in ~/.local/share/rhythmbox but I don't know exactly, as i don't use the rb podcast feature.
You could sync them by first moving the file, lets say "podcasts.xml" to ~/Ubuntu One/podcasts.xml and then
ln -s ~/"Ubuntu One"/podcasts.xml ~/.local/share/rhythmbox

But as mentioned before, I'm not sure what the exact file for podcast subscriptions is

Comment: Thank you for your answer and comment! I found out that it's possible to choose where the podcast files are downloaded to, by going to Edit → Preferences, then switch to the Podcasts tab. By choosing a folder inside ~/Ubuntu One, the podcast files are downloaded there and are synchronized, if you choose that same directory on every computer.

The same cannot be said about the list of subscribed podcasts, which are stored in the same XML file as list of songs in the library, thus it's not that easy for me to synchronize. Your answer did help, though, so I'm marking it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark your `Podcasts` folder as a synced folder to sync the podcast files themselves; you do not have to put those files inside your `Ubuntu One` folder if you don't want to. That way, you can choose whether you want your podcasts synced to other devices or not (your `Ubuntu One` folder is always kept in sync). To mark any folder as synced with Ubuntu One, just right-click it and say `Ubuntu One > Synchronise this folder`, or say `Add a folder from this computer` in the Ubuntu One control panel.

The list of subscribed podcasts in Rhythmbox is a little more difficult to synchronise, I'm afraid, because (as you note in a comment) it's not stored separately. It would be possible to write a Rhythmbox plugin to keep this data in sync as well, though; if you're a hacker and interested in doing that (or know someone who is) I'd be happy to give some tips on how best to do it.

Comment: Thank you! I would upvote your answer if I could. And yes, I'm interested in writing a plugin for Rhythmbox - I've started to learn Python some weeks ago (and have experience with PHP), if that helps :)

Comment: OK. To write a plugin you'll need to get notified when the list of podcasts changes (you'll want to talk to the Rhythmbox developers on irc to find out how to do this) and then export that list to a file somewhere in an Ubuntu One synced folder (for example, your Podcasts folder). The harder part is: you also need to monitor that file for changes while Rhythmbox is running (which you can do with Ubuntu One's SyncDaemonTool API) and re-read it if it changes.